# Does JavaScript(ES2015) have preprocessor support for omit braces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

Does JavaScript have preprocessor support for omit braces like in [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)?

For example:

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
div
  background-color red
p
  color blue
</style>

<script>
import something from './something';

export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      todos: state => state.todos;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<template lang="jade">
div
  p Hello World!
</template>
```

I want to write ES6 code that just like:

```
<script lang="?">
import something from './something'

export default
  vuex:
    getters:
      todos: state => state.todos
</scrip>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. If you don't like curly braces then check out [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/). It compiles down to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). It's a preprocessor for JavaScript that is white space sensitive, like Jade, so you often do not need a lot of punctuation.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting, but CoffeeScript is not supported on ES2015. :-(

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript/ECMAScript (as a language) does not have any preprocessor support at all, because it doesn't need compilation or preprocessing - it's an interpreted scripting language.

You can however write a custom preprocessor that does whatever you want and apply it manually to your script files.